# Methods on getting the client details on the switch

Tags: switch, ipv6

I have been working on this project and I have come to a point where I need to block the user in the network(At most in the CISCO switch)

I know I can send port shut via telnet session with a premade command but my problem is getting the users port.

I have only his IP Address for identification, is it possible to dump or get all the addresses in that switch? via telnet or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the router for that subnet and find the MAC for that IP -- if they're generating traffic, the router will have the MAC.  Then go to each switch with access ports for that subnet (could be a single switch, could be dozens) and look for the MAC in the mac-address-table.

**-- Example --**

I have forgotten the port for the management interface of my iSCSI SAN switch, but I know the IP. From a machine in the same LAN, I ping it and then look in the ARP table:

```
[root:pts/5{4}]machine:~/[01:53 PM]:arp -a | grep IP
? (IP) at d0:7e:28:d1:42:01 [ether] on eth0
```

I first login to `sw-r2-3`:

```
sw-R2-3#show mac address-table address d07e.28d1.4201
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
  55    d07e.28d1.4201    DYNAMIC     Po1
```

I know `Po1` (*port-channel 1*) is the uplink for that switch, so I go to `sw-r2-2`:

```
sw-R2-2#show mac address-table address d07e.28d1.4201           
          Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
  55    d07e.28d1.4201    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/43
```

I know G1/0/43 is an access port -- `show run int g1/0/43` -- so that's where it's connected.

Comment: Ah so its more of I need to access the router to get what I wanted. thank you will try this approach :)

Comment: Note: "router" could also be a switch. In my example, all the switches are layer-2 devices (they don't do any routing) as such, they have no layer-3 (IP) information. (other than management traffic)

Comment: Is it possible to contact the router from a an access point in the switch? via telnet or something similar? Also I assume this is possible with ipv6? =)

Comment: layer-2 (MAC) doesn't care what your layer-3 (IP, IPv6, IPX, etc.) is. It only changes the first step: finding the MAC. For linux, that's `ip -6 neigh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ARP'ing for the MAC address and find out which machine it belongs to.  Checking the ARP table on the switch can also help.